# Probability of at least one queen after drawing 2 cards

Tags: probability

Two cards are drawn from a well-shuffled deck (no replacement):
What are the chances that at least one of the two cards is a queen?

I am having trouble wrapping my head around this. Thanks!

Comment: Think of the complement of P(no queen drawn)

Comment: Maybe it is easiest to first find the probability neither is a Queen. Imagine drawing one at a time. The probability the first is not a Queen is $48/52$. Given the first was not a Queen, the probability the second is not a Queen is $\frac{47}{51}$. Continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a [tree diagram](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/probability-tree-diagrams.html), the logic does like this:

first draw has two scenarios, each with a fraction that can represent the probability of its occurrence (1 stands for 100%)

**a) Not a queen: (52-4)/52**

**b) Is a queen: 4/52**

Now, in the second draw, for each of the above scenario, there are two new scenarios:

**a1): Not a queen: (51-4)/51**

**a2): Is a queen: 4/51**

**b1): Not a queen: (51-3)/51**

**b2): Is a queen: 3/51**

Note that the number 51 comes from the fact that the total number of cards is reduced in the second draw, and the number 3 in the b) scenarios come from the fact that one of the 4 queens is drawn.

Now, you have your four cases, in three of them (a2), (b1), (b2), there is at least one queen, the probability for each of them is the product of the first fraction and the second fraction, for example, the scenario a1 has this probability:

(52-4)/52  *  (51-4)/51 = 0.851 (approximate value)

If you have done everything right, you will also find that the sum of all possibilities is equal to 1.